# ¿Porque me sale error al tratar de asignar un valor a una columna de excel mediante la librería interop?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Quiero generar reportes con la información de la BD, de hecho todo va bien salvo cuando quiero empezar a agregar la información que obtengo dentro del excel.

Código de ambientación del excel:

```
ExcelCreate.Application excelApp = new ExcelCreate.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
string workbookPath = "C:\\xxx\\xxxx\\xxx\\xxxx xxx\\xxxx\\xxxxx\\xxxx\\Excel.xlsx";
ExcelCreate.Workbook book = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, ExcelCreate.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true);
ExcelCreate.Sheets excelSheets = book.Worksheets;
string currentSheet = "Hoja1";
ExcelCreate.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (ExcelCreate.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
ExcelCreate.Range excelCell = (ExcelCreate.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A20");
```

Código de Asignación de información al excel:

```
List<tb_uploadexcel> tbUpload = new List<tb_uploadexcel>();
        tbUpload = LoadTable();
        int RowCounter=0;

        foreach (var elemento in tbUpload)
        {
            excelWorksheet.Cells[RowCounter, 1] = elemento.UserUpload; --- ERROR
            RowCounter++;
        }
```

> Mensaje de Error:
>
> Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Qué librería estas usando? es server side o client side la ejecución?

Comment: No sé si puedes asignar directamente a una celda, no sé qué librería estás usando pero normalmente se setea la propiedad cell.Value y no directamente la celda.

Comment: Creo que estás empezando en la fila 0 (RowCounter=0;) y Excel empieza las filas en la 1